# Pandas option to treat leading zeros entry as string

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is there a `read_csv` option to parse columns with leading zeros as strings? I've seen suggestions to preprocess and modify the csv to add quotes, but am wondering if one of the [52 kwargs options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) can do this for me.

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074305/how-can-i-prevent-leading-zeroes-from-being-stripped-from-columns-in-my-csv) question, but explicitly asking if there's a pandas option, rather than preprocessing or manually passing `dtype={strcols:object}`.

Comment: no specific option, see @TomAugspurger soln. too many options already!

Comment: But 1 more option for my special use case won't hurt! *50 options later...*

Comment: but you still have to specify the column(s) so not much point in that! And its better to be explicit than implicity. read_csv can parse just about everything. Furthermore how would it 'know' to do this?

Comment: I'm just kidding about the new option. But what I had in mind was just a mode to modify the type inference so as soon as it sees a leading 0 in *any column* it casts the column to string/object. I'm completely unfamiliar with the nature of how the csv parsing works though, so I wouldn't be surprised if my idea is totally infeasible to implement. Just thought I'd ask though :)

Comment: Use case is I get a bunch of csv's that have numeric codes with leading zeros that need to be treated as strings, though they otherwise look like ints (and it seems Oracle outputs these columns to csv without quotes). I'm just surprised this case isn't as common as I thought.

Comment: you can specify ``dtype=object`` to get everything as object (no infferences). Might do the trick for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Ask, and you shall receive. Specify the dtype as a dictionary of {column name: type} :

```
In [22]: s = """0001,2
0002,3
"""

In [23]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None, dtype={0: str})
Out[23]: 
      0  1
0  0001  2
1  0002  3

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I've been using this, but was wondering about an option that doesn't require manual column specification (last sentence). But @Jeff seems to be indicating there's no other way. Didn't know about col integer indexing in `dtype` arg though, thanks.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you mean by manually passing that dict.